# Prove that $R$ has $2^{k}$ elements

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

> If $G$ is a group of odd order made up of the units of commutative ring $R$, then we have to show that $|R|$ is of the form of $2^{k}$.

What I have figured out is if the order of the group is odd we cannot have an even order element in the group (by Lagrange theorem) so if $a\in G $ then $a\ne a^{-1} $ and $a^{-1}\in G$. Now 1 is a unit and $1\in G $ and so $-1\in G$. The order has automatically become even,  we need to make it odd so that is not possible as the units will come in pair .can the group of units have an odd order?

If the above proposition is not true what counter example can I give?

Comment: By hypothesis, the ring R has to be finite, since there are infinite rings having 1 as their only invertible element.

Answer (score 4):

The ring $R$ must have characteristic two (because $-1=1$), and hence be an algebra over the field with two elements. Being a vector space, its order must therefore be a power of two.

Comment: I didn't get it. I was thinking that o(-1) in G is 2 but |G| is odd so o(-1) should divide G which is a contradiction.

Comment: @GuriaSona $-1\in G$ and $(-1)^{\mathrm{ord}(G)}=1$, so $-1=1$. This shows that $R$ contains the field with two elements.

Comment: @GeoffreyTrang R has to be finite in order to conclude that its number of elements is a power of 2.